# Kivy filechooser questions

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using filechooser based on the Kivy example demo:

The .kv file:

```
        FileChooserListView:
            id: list_view_tab
            path: '.'
            on_selection: nada = app.loader(list_view_tab.selection)

        FileChooserIconView:
            id: icon_view_tab
            show_hidden: True
            on_selection: nada = app.loader(icon_view_tab.selection)

...

    TextInput:
        size_hint: (None, 1)
        id: filtro
        text: '*.py'
        multiline: False
        on_text: list_view_tab.filters = icon_view_tab.filters = text.split(',')
```

There are no direct references to these widgets in the .py code, and it shows the file system ok both ways.

I have these questions:

- The filter doesn't work. What have I missed?
- In the `FileChooserListView` there are the column names `Name` and `Size`. How can I change these for other languages?
- How can I select files by **single click**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The filter doesn't work. What have I missed?

You set the `filter` property for both your FileChooserListViews, but this doesn't seem to exist. You should instead set the `filters` property, which must be a list of strings. This is documented [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html) in the kivy doc.

> In the FileChooserListView there are the column names Name and Size. How can I change these for other languages?

I don't think this is exposed in the api, though it probably should be. For now, you probably have to change your kivy source. The relevant lines are in the FileChooserListView rule of kivy/data/style.kv, you can find them [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/style.kv#L256) in kivy's github.

> How can I select files by single click?

I'm not sure about the best way, but I might look into the `selection` property of the FileChooserListView. As a kivy property, this will call the method `on_selection` when the selection changes, so you can put your desired behaviour there.

There may be some fiddliness with exactly how and when the selection changes, but it seems like the right sort of thing.

Comment: Using `on_selection` worked, but the changes I made to the filters didn't. I am using the version 1.7 that comes with Ubuntu. Could it make a difference?

Comment: It is possible. Could you add your changes to your original post?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x1gUNoVB2I  here is an example of using filechooser with single click